# Force Download Images using PHP

Tags: php, android

I am trying to download an image from website using php with the following code.

Currently it idendtify and downloads the file. but the 
file downloaded is not opening and it shows as corrupted. what is the issue in the below code ?

Also I am embedding this page in one of my mobile app. will it work in mobile android devices too

```
<?php
$file = "http://example.com/animals/1.jpg";
    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($file);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) 
    {
        case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
        case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
        default: die('Wrong Extension');
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Test".basename($file)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data stream to browser.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); // change this will work for you.
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried with given code. But still its showing the same thing that the image is corrupted or damaged or too large and cannot be opened.
I see a image size is slightly reduced. The original image was 9kb, but the downloaded image is 8kb. is that something causing issue ?